# Fetching content order by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, bolt-cms

Documentation: https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching#ordering-results

I'm trying to fetch a set of records and order them based on two fields. I have created the following request to do so:

```
{% setcontent records = 'artists' where { gender: 'Male' } orderby 'surname, title ASC' %}
```

This works fine when using `bolt.db` as the database but in MySQL it does not. I have the feeling that I have done something similar to this before so I'm wondering if it's version change related. This implementation is using `v1.6.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've got this working with a quick fix.

What I've done is modified the `Storage.php` file ever so slightly.

```
private function getEscapedSortorder($name, $prefix = 'r')
{   
    // HACK: multiple sort columns
    if (strpos($name, ',') !== FALSE) {
        return $name;
    }
    // END HACK: multiple sort columns

    list ($name, $asc) = $this->getSortOrder($name);

    ...
```

In my contenttypes I can now define `sort: surname, title` which will automatically do the `ASC` order, or I could do `sort: surname DESC, title ASC` or whatever SQL will allow really.

This could easily be modified to handle `-surname, -title`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I've not tested this but the usual syntax for MySQL would be:

```
order  surname ASC, title ASC
```

try tweaking the orderby string to be the same format and see if that does the job.